Who has the final say in making revisions to a manuscript after it has been returned by reviewers?
You wrote a paper as first author and submitted to a journal. Months later, you get the paper back with suggested revisions from reviewers. One of your much more senior and accomplished co-authors wants you to do a lot more revisions than what the reviewers suggest, and mostly things that have nothing to do with the reviewers' requests.
My questions on this are:

Ignoring whether or not your assessment of your co-author's suggestions are correct, who has final say in these revisions?

If you were the first author, how would you communicate to your senior co-author?

If you cannot agree, how do these things get resolved?

How does your answer change in each of the following additional contexts:

The senior co-author is the principal investigator (in my opinion, in this case, you simply follow them).
The paper was written when you and your co-authors were still in the same organization (with you as junior to them), but now you are all in other jobs in other places.




If you are working as an RA or untenured professor, you'd do well to listen to the other colleauge.

@JosephDoggie I agree. See 4.1. Thanks.

No one has the "final say", you have to come to an agreement among all coauthors.
If you disagree with your coauthors, I would make your case to them respectfully. The specifics of that interaction are quite culturally dependent but would not be special to this circumstance.
Consider that if you have less experience publishing than your coauthors you may defer to their expertise. But also changing parts of a paper not commented on by reviewers is a bit unusual and may lengthen the review process; in some cases it absolutely must be done (like if some mistake was discovered) but in other cases it should have been done before initial submission. On the other hand, if there is something new and exciting to add there may be strategic benefit.

Thank you. I certainly agree that talking should be the first course of action. Would you mind including your answers to #3 and #4? For #3 specifically, if the authors cannot agree, does the paper just die?

@tommyB Yes, which puts a high incentive on agreeing. I'm not going to address 4 it doesn't seem important to me.

@tommyB What alternative is there? You are forced to sign your name under an article you no longer agree with? That would be wrong in so many ways. So yeah, if you collaborate you need unanimity, and no unanimity means no paper.

For number #3 it is also possible for the disagreeing co-authors to remove their name from the paper.

One obvious thing you could do, if you haven't already, is try to get some clarification from the senior coauthor. Specifically, what's their reasoning for suggesting revisions that are not in response to the reviews?
Without any other information, it could be anything from "sorry, I didn't really think about it before" to "actually these are in response to the reviewer and here's the reason why" to "I consider these to be serious problems that we need to fix before publishing, independently of the review", or something else.
Depending on their reasoning, it might then be appropriate to suggest skipping some of the suggestions on the basis that the reviewer didn't ask for them, or to ask the senior author to implement some of them. But depending on their personality and your relationship you might have to be careful in asking about this. I would probably try to do all this in a meeting / zoom call, rather than by email.

Thank you. Yes, definitely talking and trying to clarify and reason would be the first course and hopefully only action needed. I was merely thinking of the worst and seeking insight on what protocol was. Also, I chuckled a little at the "ask the senior author to implement some of them" suggestion. Thank you for that.
